# Angular json data - remove "qutoes" from results

Tags: angularjs, json

```
            <li ng-repeat="doc in indexVM.results.hits.hits">
                {{doc._source.description | json | limitTo: 500}} 
            </li>
```

The above will return a result based on search term e.g. search for help 
would return "help"

Is there something I can do to remove the "quotations"?

Comment: can you show a sample of the actual data you are trying to display?  and since `doc._source.description` should be a singular element, are you *sure* you need the `json` filter? and what are you expecting the `limitTo` filter to do in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**json filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json) is mostly used for debugging and will always display strings values in `"quotes"`. This is the desired behavior to make it clearer as to what types of data you're dealing with when it's retrieved from an API for example.

You could just remove the `json` filter to fix this:

```
<li ng-repeat="doc in indexVM.results.hits.hits">
  {{doc._source.description | limitTo: 500}} 
</li>
```